# Java Coding Console and .jar library files.

Tags: java, jar, console

I have installed  Java SE Development Kit 8u77 for Windows x64. I have also installed Java for desktop, Version 8 Update 77. Will this suffice for me to start coding. Also I did NOT manage to open the window for coding. How can I open a coding console ? How do I install .jar libraries ? Obviously I'm skipping a few 100 steps and trying to do something a couple Levels up, though Im at Level 0. Help !!

Comment: `Also I did NOT manage to open the window for coding.` - there is none. Open an editor and write code (source files are text files) or use an IDE auch as Netbeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA which are basically editors with additional features. You might want to start with some tutorial to cover the basics, e.g. have a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think you should search the web for a beginners tutorial (don't ask here for it). Or buy a book. Sorry if that sounds rude ...

Answer (score 0):

The only things you really need to start coding are:

- The JDK (check)
- notepad (though when more advanced, an IDE can come in handy - check)
- command prompt (check)

> I'm skipping a few 100 steps

Don't. All that will lead to, is you as 'experienced' developer come here to ask questions a beginner is (or should be) able to solve without problems.